# how to create a mixin js in magento

Tags: magento2, requirejs, mixins

in my case i want to add a mixing for just a single line but i can't achieve that

the parent js file is ==> web/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/model/customer/address.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define(['underscore'], function (_) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Returns new address object.
     *
     * @param {Object} addressData
     * @return {Object}
     */
    return function (addressData) {
        var regionId;

        if (addressData.region['region_id'] && addressData.region['region_id'] !== '0') {
            regionId = addressData.region['region_id'] + '';
        }

        return {
            customerAddressId: addressData.id,
            email: addressData.email,
            countryId: addressData['country_id'],
            regionId: regionId,
            regionCode: addressData.region['region_code'],
            region: addressData.region.region,
            customerId: addressData['customer_id'],
            street: addressData.street,
            company: addressData.company,
            telephone: addressData.telephone,
            fax: addressData.fax,
            postcode: addressData.postcode,
            city: addressData.city,
            firstname: addressData.firstname,
            lastname: addressData.lastname,
            middlename: addressData.middlename,
            prefix: addressData.prefix,
            suffix: addressData.suffix,
            vatId: addressData['vat_id'],
            sameAsBilling: addressData['same_as_billing'],
            saveInAddressBook: addressData['save_in_address_book'],
            customAttributes: _.toArray(addressData['custom_attributes']).reverse(),

            /**
             * @return {*}
             */
            isDefaultShipping: function () {
                return addressData['default_shipping'];
            },

            /**
             * @return {*}
             */
            isDefaultBilling: function () {
                return addressData['default_billing'];
            },

            /**
             * @return {*}
             */
            getAddressInline: function () {
                return addressData.inline;
            },

            /**
             * @return {String}
             */
            getType: function () {
                return 'customer-address';
            },

            /**
             * @return {String}
             */
            getKey: function () {
                return this.getType() + this.customerAddressId;
            },

            /**
             * @return {String}
             */
            getCacheKey: function () {
                return this.getKey();
            },

            /**
             * @return {Boolean}
             */
            isEditable: function () {
                return false;
            },

            /**
             * @return {Boolean}
             */
            canUseForBilling: function () {
                return true;
            }
        };
    };
});
```

i want just to change this line :

```
customAttributes: _.toArray(addressData['custom_attributes']).reverse(),
```

by this line :

```
customAttributes: addressData['custom_attributes'],
```

PS ; i want to do it by mixing not copying and past all of the file content

this is some try from me :

1. adding requirejs-config.js,  2) adding the file adsress-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function($) {

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
                customAttributes: addressData['custom_attributes'],

        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two catches here with this type of mixin (there are a couple of ways to use mixins):

1. The original `Magento_Customer/js/model/customer/address` returns a javascript function
2. The object you are trying to mixin on is the **result** of the original function

## Extend JS Function

When a requirejs definition returns a plain javascript function/object, you'll want to use the `mage/utils/wrapper` utility.

[Magento DevDocs > Javascript Mixins > Extend JS Function](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html#extend-js-function)

**Mixin Configuration**

Configured either in module or theme.

```js
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer/address': {
                '[Vendor]_[ModuleName]/js/model/customer/address-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Mixin Using Wrapper Approach**

1. **Wrap** the original function with your own
2. Call the original function to get its result, making sure to pass in any original arguments, in this case `addressData`
3. Alter the resulting object property you wanted to change the value for
4. Return altered result

```js
define([
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function (wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function (addressModel) {
        return wrapper.wrap(addressModel, function (originalAddressModel, addressData) {
           var result =  originalAddressModel(addressData);
           result.customAttributes = addressData['custom_attributes'];
           return result;
        });
    };
});
```