# Rewrite js method issue using mixin

Tags: magento2, javascript

This is the original js file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/resource-url-manager.js`, which I want to extend:

```
define([
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
    'mageUtils'
], function (customer, urlBuilder, utils) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            /**
             * @param {Object} quote
             * @return {*}
             */
            getUrlForTotalsEstimationForNewAddress: function (quote) {
                var params = this.getCheckoutMethod() == 'guest' ? //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                        {
                            cartId: quote.getQuoteId()
                        } : {},
                    urls = {
                        'guest': '/guest-carts/:cartId/totals-information',
                        'customer': '/carts/mine/totals-information'
                    };

                return this.getUrl(urls, params);
            },
.....
```

This is the `requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/model/resource-url-manager-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and this is the mixin file: `resource-url-manager-mixin` :

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Component'
], function ($, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        getUrlForTotalsEstimationForNewAddress: function() {
             this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

But I am getting this js error: `Uncaught Error: Script error for: Component`.

I've also tried like this:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        getUrlForTotalsEstimationForNewAddress: function (quote) {
            this._super();
        }
    };
    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

But still getting a js error from `target`.

My goal is to rewrite this method: `getUrlForTotalsEstimationForNewAddress`. Any clue what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not all mixins are created/used exactly the same, the differences coming from whether the original thing is a Component, Vanilla JS Function/Object, jQuery widget, etc:

[Magento StackOverflow - How to create a mixin JS in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/346551/how-to-create-a-mixin-js-in-magento/346552#346552)

[Magento DevDocs - Javascript Mixins > Extend JS Object](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html#extend-js-object)

#### Extend Javascript Object Method

The key part here is to require the `mage/utils/wrapper` library. It contains a `wrap` function (and other similar functions) that lets you effectively create an around plugin on the original function.

##### Wrapper.wrap()

Wraps target function with a specified wrapper, which will receive
reference to the original function as a first argument.

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
    
    let mixin = function (originalFn, quote) {
        return originalFn(quote);
    };

    return function (target) {
        target.getUrlForTotalsEstimationForNewAddress = wrapper.wrap(target.getUrlForTotalsEstimationForNewAddress, mixin);

        return target;
    };
});
```

##### Wrapper.wrapSuper()

Wraps the incoming function to implement support of the '_super' method.

**Note:** I haven't used this but saw it in the `mage/utils/wrapper` source code and it's used in the Magento DevDocs example.

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    let mixin = function (quote) {
        return this._super(quote);
    };

    return function (target) {
        target.getUrlForTotalsEstimationForNewAddress = wrapper.wrapSuper(target.getUrlForTotalsEstimationForNewAddress, mixin);

        return target;
    };
});
```

##### Wrapper.extend()

Extends target object with provided extenders. If property in target and extender objects is a function, then it will be wrapped using 'wrap' method.

**Note:** I haven't used this but saw it in the `mage/utils/wrapper` source code.

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    let mixin = {
        getUrlForTotalsEstimationForNewAddress: function (originalFn, quote) {
            return originalFn(quote);
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return wrapper.extend(target, mixin);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `'Component'` is not a correct alias, maybe you mean to use `'uiComponent'`?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Well, I don't get any js errors, but neither my rewritten method is not triggered. I 've changed `Component` with `uiComponent`. Thanks

Comment: If you add a console log/breakpoint in resource-url-manager-mixin underneath 'use strict' is it called? If so it's probably because resource-url-manager.js only returns an object and not a UI Component